# how can a user login to two totally separate sharepoints and have both open simultaneously

Tags: deployment

how can a user login to two totally separate sharepoints and have both open simultaneously?  My end users have more than one sharepoint app that they want to have open at a single time, like they do for other apps.  surely there must be a way.

Comment: Like using IE and Chrome at the same time? Or  multiple browser tabs?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not on single-sign-on, then you can open two separate sharepoint URLs using different accounts by opening them in different browsers. Alternatively, you can go InPrivate/InCognito mode in the same browser.

Assuming you are on single-sign-on, you still need a separate browser or an InPrivate mode of the same browser to open your second URL. Modify the link your second url to the following format:
http:///_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true

You should now be able to logged in as another user for the second site.